# Did anyone ever actually take home the goat from "Let's Make A Deal"?

Tags: lets-make-a-deal

After reading today's [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1282/), I've actually become curious.  Is there any record of a contestant actually wanting to go home with the goat (or other Zonk!) on Let's Make a Deal?

Comment: I've never seen the show, but I'd guess the goat is not actually a prize, simply representative of 'losing'.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, they were considered an "undesirable prize".  As such, contestants would have had legal claim to the animals, but most contestants would choose the cash equivalent.

Comment: Are game shows even on topic here?

Comment: @Flimzy Hard to say, but it seems so. Might even deserve a meta discussion?

Comment: I'm not sure why they wouldn't be.  Game Shows are a very large part of "Television".  Please add a meta-link if a post is made.

Comment: @RLH: News and current events shows are not on-topic, and they are a huge part of television. And game shows seem more closely related to talk shows than to scripted shows.  But then reality TV I suppose is on-topic... so... *shrug*

Comment: @Flimzy... That's interesting.  Personally, I've always classified game shows as "the original reality TV".  That, and Candid Camera.  IMHO, these types of shows were the beginning of the "essence" of what is modern reality TV.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Make_a_Deal#Format) for Let's Make a Deal:

> Prizes generally are either a legitimate prize, cash, or a "Zonk".
>   Legitimate prizes run the gamut of what is typically given away on
>   game shows, including trips, electronics, furniture, appliances, and
>   cars. Zonks are unwanted booby prizes (e.g., live animals, large
>   amounts of food, fake money, fake trips or something outlandish such
>   as a giant article of clothing, a room full of junked furniture,
>   etc.). Sometimes Zonks are legitimate prizes but of a low value (e.g.,
>   Matchbox cars, wheelbarrows, T-shirts, grocery prizes, etc.). On rare
>   occasions, a trader appears to get Zonked, but the Zonk is a cover-up
>   for a legitimate prize.
>
> Though usually considered joke prizes, traders
>   legally win the Zonks. However, after the taping of the show, any
>   trader who had been Zonked is offered a consolation prize (currently
>   $100) instead of having to take home the actual Zonk. This is partly
>   because some of the Zonks are intrinsically or physically impossible
>   to receive or deliver to the traders (such as live animals or the guy
>   in an animal costume), or the props/employees are owned by the studio.
>   A disclaimer at the end of the credits of later 1970s episodes read
>   "Some traders accept reasonable duplicates of Zonk prizes."

To back this up, this is from an [interview with Monty Hall](http://www.tvparty.com/gamemonty2.html), one of the first presenters:

> **Interviewer:** People who got stuck with the "zonks," the joke prizes, were they
>   good-natured about losing out?
>
> **Monty Hall:** In 4,700 shows, I got kissed 50,000 times. Even when they
>   lost, they were very nice about it. But you know the law in game shows
>   - if you go on a show and you win a donkey, that's your prize. You're entitled to it. So if a person won one of our zonks, they could take
>   it home. But in 99 percent of the cases, we would offer them something
>   after the show - a washer and dryer or a color TV or something,
>   instead of that very valuable zonk, and they would take it. In 1
>   percent of the cases, they didn't.
>
> There was a time when a farmer won five calves and he wanted the
>   calves. That cost me a fortune because when you rent them from the
>   animal place, they're expensive. And there were other cases like that.
>   Like people won dogs; they would keep dogs. They wouldn't keep cats.
>   They would keep dogs. It was a very genial atmosphere, over 27 years.

So despite the "zonks" being joke prizes, people did indeed take them home on rare occasions. I'm sorry to say I haven't found an example of a *goat* being taken home, but I'm hoping a *calf* will do!

Comment: Wow! I'm not sure how I missed the notification that you had answered my question.  This is what I had hoped to find.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once I saw a Zonk on the old "Let's Make a Deal" it was some kind of Animal (maybe a baby elephant or something) and I guess it was actually worth so much money Monty Hall let her trade it for a chance at the Big Deal at the end of the show, I only saw this happen one time on all the old "Let's Make a Deal" reruns I've seen, so it's obviously very rare that a Zonk was worth a lot of money like that.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Movies & TV Stack Exchange! While your answer appears to be helpful, it would benefit from having a reliable source, otherwise it comes off more of comment. Eventually you will have enough reputation to leave an actual comment in the comment section.

Answer (score -2):

Zonks are not actually prizes.  You get $100 (or was it $200) in lieu of the Zonk.  I know because I have been in the back room during prize paperwork time. :)

Comment: Monty Hall begs to differ.

Comment: This isn't an unreasonable response, however, you may need to provide a bit of clarification.  Why were you backstage?  Was this for the original show, or the newer one?  Did you (or do you) work for the television station that produces LMAD?  I'd be interested in finding out more, but for this to be an acceptable answer, you need to give a better, more objective response.